# Using Numpy Array Conditional Operation Mask with Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, conditional-formatting

I am new to Tensoflow and I try to implement it in a custom RNN project to learn more about how Neural Networks work.

My problem is simple but I don't seem to find any satisfying answer.

I am used to Numpy and operations on arrays using condition masks but I don't find a way to transform this with Tensors

```
def ELu(in_array):
    in_array[in_array<= 0] = math.e ** in_array[in_array<= 0] - 1
    return in_array

>>>print(ELu(np.array([1.0,0.0,-1.0])))
```

Gives me

```
[ 1.          0.         -0.63212056]
```

And I would like to edit that function to be able to give me a similar Tensor if I do something like this

```
>>>print(ELu(tf.convert_to_tensor([1.0,0.0,-1.0])))
```

Which should give me

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 1.,  0., -0.63212056], dtype=float32)>
```

but accessing a tensor using a similar way `in_array[in_array<= 0]` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tensor_scatter_nd_update()`:

```
import math
def ELu(in_array):
  mask = in_array <= 0
  inds = tf.where(mask)
  updates = tf.boolean_mask(in_array, mask)
  updates = math.e ** updates - 1.
  res = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(in_array, inds, updates)
  return res
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I'll start using those functions more often!